# build failing in create react if there are lint errors after ejecting

Tags: create-react-app

I was able to run "npm start" before ejecting CRA.
After I performed "npm run eject" build is getting failed due to lint errors and unable to run localhost.

If linting errors are reasons behind build failed, why app was working before ejecting?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable that by adding `emitWarning: true` to the options of `eslint-loader`.

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
    enforce: "pre",
    use: [
      {
        options: {
          formatter: eslintFormatter,
          eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint"),
          emitWarning: true,
        },
        loader: require.resolve("eslint-loader"),
      },
    ],
    include: paths.appSrc,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have configured Eslint and Airbnb with following versions.

```
"eslint": "^5.5.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1"
```

After ejecting I found that in package.json there are two different versions of eslint.
So I think due to version mismatch of eslint that Airbnb and CreateReactApp require app building is getting failed.

[Some reference](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3540)